# Nested loop on json data

Tags: python, json

i have the json below which i need to collect fields from "outcomes"

```
[
    {
        "eventId": 1018663065,
        "criterion": {
            "englishLabel": "First Touchdown Scorer - Including Overtime",
            "id": 1001488021,
            "label": "First Touchdown Scorer - Including Overtime",
            "order": 
            [
                1
            ]
        },
        "tags": 
        [
            "OFFERED_PREMATCH",
            "BET_BUILDER"
        ],
        "outcomes": 
        [
            {
                "oddsFractional": "20/1",
                "englishLabel": "Wentz, Carson",
                "label": "Wentz, Carson",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "2000",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Wentz, Carson",
                "participantId": 1003128420,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:37:28Z",
                "odds": 21000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232074,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000334
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "45/1",
                "englishLabel": "No Touchdown",
                "label": "No Touchdown",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "4500",
                "type": "OT_NO_GOAL",
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:23:02Z",
                "odds": 46000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232086,
                "status": "OPEN"
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "22/1",
                "englishLabel": "McKissic, JD",
                "label": "McKissic, JD",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "2200",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "McKissic, JD",
                "participantId": 1003405978,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:47:21Z",
                "odds": 23000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232100,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000334
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "21/2",
                "englishLabel": "Gibson, Antonio",
                "label": "Gibson, Antonio",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "1050",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Gibson, Antonio",
                "participantId": 1006035581,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:47:21Z",
                "odds": 11500,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232109,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000334
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "21/2",
                "englishLabel": "Robinson Jr., Brian",
                "label": "Robinson Jr., Brian",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "1050",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Robinson Jr., Brian",
                "participantId": 1007667637,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:47:21Z",
                "odds": 11500,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232117,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000334
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "45/1",
                "englishLabel": "Griffin, Ryan",
                "label": "Griffin, Ryan",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "4500",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Griffin, Ryan",
                "participantId": 1002198957,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:37:28Z",
                "odds": 46000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232126,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000178
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "30/1",
                "englishLabel": "Pettis, Dante",
                "label": "Pettis, Dante",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "3000",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Pettis, Dante",
                "participantId": 1003741140,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:37:28Z",
                "odds": 31000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232134,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000178
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "18/1",
                "englishLabel": "St. Brown, Equanimeous",
                "label": "St. Brown, Equanimeous",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "1800",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "St. Brown, Equanimeous",
                "participantId": 1004561624,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:37:28Z",
                "odds": 19000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232140,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000178
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "14/1",
                "englishLabel": "Kmet, Cole",
                "label": "Kmet, Cole",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "1400",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Kmet, Cole",
                "participantId": 1005209906,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:37:28Z",
                "odds": 15000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232146,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000178
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "29/1",
                "englishLabel": "Harry, N’Keal",
                "label": "Harry, N’Keal",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "2900",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Harry, N’Keal",
                "participantId": 1005252420,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:37:28Z",
                "odds": 30000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232153,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000178
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "8/1",
                "englishLabel": "Fields, Justin",
                "label": "Fields, Justin",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "800",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Fields, Justin",
                "participantId": 1005289956,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:33:24Z",
                "odds": 9000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232159,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000178
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "5/1",
                "englishLabel": "Montgomery, David",
                "label": "Montgomery, David",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "510",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Montgomery, David",
                "participantId": 1005330489,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:37:28Z",
                "odds": 6100,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232164,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000178
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "66/1",
                "englishLabel": "Blasingame, Khari",
                "label": "Blasingame, Khari",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "6600",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Blasingame, Khari",
                "participantId": 1005619153,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:33:24Z",
                "odds": 67000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232170,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000178
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "70/1",
                "englishLabel": "Wesco, Trevon",
                "label": "Wesco, Trevon",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "7000",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Wesco, Trevon",
                "participantId": 1005620092,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:23:02Z",
                "odds": 71000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232176,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000178
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "60/1",
                "englishLabel": "Smith-Marsette, Ihmir",
                "label": "Smith-Marsette, Ihmir",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "6000",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Smith-Marsette, Ihmir",
                "participantId": 1005740936,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:37:28Z",
                "odds": 61000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232181,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000178
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "35/1",
                "englishLabel": "Ebner, Trestan",
                "label": "Ebner, Trestan",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "3500",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Ebner, Trestan",
                "participantId": 1005999128,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:33:24Z",
                "odds": 36000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232186,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000178
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "21/2",
                "englishLabel": "Mooney, Darnell",
                "label": "Mooney, Darnell",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "1050",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Mooney, Darnell",
                "participantId": 1006797242,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:23:02Z",
                "odds": 11500,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232190,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000178
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "14/1",
                "englishLabel": "Herbert, Khalil",
                "label": "Herbert, Khalil",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "1400",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Herbert, Khalil",
                "participantId": 1007051724,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:33:24Z",
                "odds": 15000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232194,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000178
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "80/1",
                "englishLabel": "Tonges, Jake",
                "label": "Tonges, Jake",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "8000",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Tonges, Jake",
                "participantId": 1007678491,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:23:02Z",
                "odds": 81000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232197,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000178
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "29/1",
                "englishLabel": "Jones Jr., Velus",
                "label": "Jones Jr., Velus",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "2900",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Jones Jr., Velus",
                "participantId": 1007905969,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:37:28Z",
                "odds": 30000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232200,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000178
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "15/1",
                "englishLabel": "Any other Chicago Bears player",
                "label": "Any other Chicago Bears player",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "1500",
                "type": "OT_ANY_OTHER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Chicago Bears",
                "participantId": 1000000178,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:23:02Z",
                "odds": 16000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232205,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000178
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "10/1",
                "englishLabel": "Samuel, Curtis",
                "label": "Samuel, Curtis",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "1000",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Samuel, Curtis",
                "participantId": 1002450777,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:47:21Z",
                "odds": 11000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232259,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000334
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "40/1",
                "englishLabel": "Sims, Cam",
                "label": "Sims, Cam",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "4000",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Sims, Cam",
                "participantId": 1003050339,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:47:21Z",
                "odds": 41000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232265,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000334
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "17/2",
                "englishLabel": "McLaurin, Terry",
                "label": "McLaurin, Terry",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "850",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "McLaurin, Terry",
                "participantId": 1003741186,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:47:21Z",
                "odds": 9500,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232268,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000334
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "16/1",
                "englishLabel": "Thomas, Logan",
                "label": "Thomas, Logan",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "1600",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Thomas, Logan",
                "participantId": 1004231988,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:47:21Z",
                "odds": 17000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232271,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000334
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "16/1",
                "englishLabel": "Dotson, Jahan",
                "label": "Dotson, Jahan",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "1600",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Dotson, Jahan",
                "participantId": 1005740692,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:47:21Z",
                "odds": 17000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232274,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000334
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "70/1",
                "englishLabel": "Milne, Dax",
                "label": "Milne, Dax",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "7000",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Milne, Dax",
                "participantId": 1007029029,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:23:02Z",
                "odds": 71000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232277,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000334
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "24/1",
                "englishLabel": "Brown, Dyami",
                "label": "Brown, Dyami",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "2400",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Brown, Dyami",
                "participantId": 1007094475,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:47:21Z",
                "odds": 25000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232279,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000334
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "60/1",
                "englishLabel": "Turner, Cole",
                "label": "Turner, Cole",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "6000",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Turner, Cole",
                "participantId": 1007180703,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:23:02Z",
                "odds": 61000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232281,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000334
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "75/1",
                "englishLabel": "Rogers, Armani",
                "label": "Rogers, Armani",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "7500",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Rogers, Armani",
                "participantId": 1007800362,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:23:02Z",
                "odds": 76000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232283,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000334
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "25/1",
                "englishLabel": "Bates, John",
                "label": "Bates, John",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "2500",
                "type": "OT_PLAYER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Bates, John",
                "participantId": 1007957637,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:47:21Z",
                "odds": 26000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232285,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000334
            },
            {
                "oddsFractional": "15/1",
                "englishLabel": "Any other Washington Commanders player",
                "label": "Any other Washington Commanders player",
                "betOfferId": 2349921831,
                "oddsAmerican": "1500",
                "type": "OT_ANY_OTHER_PARTICIPANT",
                "participant": "Washington Commanders",
                "participantId": 1000000334,
                "changedDate": "2022-10-12T12:23:02Z",
                "odds": 16000,
                "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
                "id": 3172232289,
                "status": "OPEN",
                "eventParticipantId": 1000000334
            }
        ],
        "cashOutStatus": "ENABLED",
        "closed": "2022-10-14T00:15:00Z",
        "betOfferType": {
            "englishName": "Player Occurrence Number",
            "name": "Player Occurrence Number",
            "id": 125
        },
        "id": 2349921831
    }
]
```

I have this code that only collects the data for the first player. I assume I need to use a nested loop to collect the player's data in the outcomes section of the JSON, but I have not been able to come up with a solution.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
    url = f"{Base_url}/betoffer/event/{','.join(map(str, event_ids))}.json?app_id={AppID}&app_key={AppKey}&local={Country}&site={Site}&type=125"
    print(url)

    player_td_data = requests.get(url).text
    player_td_data = json.loads(player_td_data)

    for td_data in player_td_data['betOffers']:
        if td_data['criterion']['label'] == 'First Touchdown Scorer - Including Overtime' and 'OFFERED_PREMATCH' in td_data['tags']:
            event_id = td_data['eventId']
            participant_id = td_data['outcomes'][0]['participantId']
            player = td_data['outcomes'][0]['participant']
            player_anytime_td_odds = td_data['outcomes'][0]['odds']
            market_status = td_data['outcomes'][0]['status']

            print(f'{event_id} {participant_id} {player} {player_anytime_td_odds} {market_status}')
```

`code`

Comment: `for outcome in td_data['outcomes']:` `participant_id = outcome['participantId']` etc.

Comment: No need to iterate if only the first player is required, e.g.: `player = td_data[0]['outcomes'][0]['participant']` Note that is `td_data[0]`, not `td_data`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the nested data. The following code will create a list of tuples from the `td_data['outcomes']` list. The `map()` function applies the `get_outcome_data()` function to each item in `td_data['outcomes']` and returns an iterable object which is transformed into a `list`. I prefer to use this method over the `for ... in:` loop because it simplifies the code.

```
def get_outcome_data(outcome):
    participant_id = outcome['participantId']
    player = outcome['participant']
    odds = outcome['odds']
    status = outcome['status']
    return (participant_id, player, odds, status)

outcomes = list(map(get_outcome_data, td_data['outcomes']))
```